# set attributes of custom tag in iText PdfHTML C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I created custom tag using PdfHTML.

```
<condition align="right">Text</condition>
```

Created custom tag for "condition" to change the value of "Text". It worked. It appeared as "P tag" in the pdf. But it doesn't take attribute align="right". I is always left aligned. How can I set attributes. Created custom css class with below code segment to text alignment.

```
 if (container != null && cssProps.containsKey(CssConstants.TEXT_ALIGN)) {
            cssProps.put(CssConstants.TEXT_ALIGN, "right");
            BackgroundApplierUtil.applyBackground(cssProps, context, container);
        }
```

It doesn't work. Please help me to solve this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It'll be greate [to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise, no one can help with unknown issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. My mistake is using, "BackgroundApplierUtil.applyBackground(cssProps, context, container)" to apply font.

```
if (container != null && cssProps.containsKey(CssConstants.TEXT_ALIGN)) {
            cssProps.put(CssConstants.TEXT_ALIGN, "right");
            FontStyleApplierUtil.ApplyFontStyles(cssProps, context,stylecontainer ,container);
        }
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-5-custom-tag-workers-and-css-appliers

This link details everything you need to know about custom tags within iText PDF.

Comment: Tried custom css property tag as below.  It goes inside the if condition and add  the property. But the text displayed in the pdf as left align.                                                                                                              if (container != null && cssProps.containsKey(CssConstants.TEXT_ALIGN)) {
            cssProps.Add(CssConstants.TEXT_ALIGN, "right");
            BackgroundApplierUtil.applyBackground(cssProps, context, container);
        }